# Load Tinymce content into regular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

H'm using Tinymce as text editor when creating email templates. When I´ve added a template with Tinymce I would like to render the content inside a div. The content in the div shall look exactly like it does in Tinymce.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Kind regard / H